# which kprobe hooks can I attach eBPF programs to?

Tags: ebpf, kprobe

I am learning about eBPF and I understand that I can attach my eBPF programs to kprobes, uprobes, tracepoints and more. I see that there is a list of for tracepoints under /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ where I can attach eBPF programs to. However, how do I find which kprobe functions I can break into, say TCP related ones? Also, how do I find those function signatures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach a kprobe to **nearly all functions of your kernel** (provided they have not been inlined when compiling the kernel). One way to list those functions is through **`cat /proc/kallsyms`**. In your case, grep for `tcp` on that file? As for the signatures, I don't believe there is a place to get them other than by **reading the kernel sources** for your kernel version.

Note that, because kernel functions are not part of the user API, there is no guarantee regarding the stability of their signature (which could be a reason why a list of signatures would make little sense—other than the huge number of signatures to list). If you want your eBPF programs to be more robust and portable between different kernel versions, you should have a look at [CO-RE](https://ebpf.io/blog/ebpf-updates-2020-12#did-you-know-co-re).

Comment: Not all kernel functions. Functions in `/sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/blacklist` cannot be attached to. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/kprobes.html#blacklist.

Comment: Hence the “nearly” :p. But thanks for the precision!

Comment: Please make the "nearly" bold. I only read bold text :-D

Comment: Done. _Takes note to buy glasses for pchaigno for their next birthday._

Comment: @Qeole can u please tell if I need to trap any kernel function then do I need to write `SEC("kprobe/sys_write")` to trap `sys_write` system call? And my SEC attribute will be enough if loaded correctly along with function definition?

Comment: All depends on whether your loader is able to interpret this section name. If you load with libbpf, or with bpftool (which relies on libbpf), then yes, it should be enough.

Comment: @Qeole can u also please tell is uprobe ebpf program does it attach to userspace some program function. Is there any sample for that in kernel source or any tutorial with libbpf?

Comment: Yes uprobes attach to user space functions. There are a few examples here and there although not as many as for kprobes. Try grepping for `uprobes` in `kernel/samples/` in the kernel repo maybe. BCC has a few examples, `sslsniff` is an interesting one. Have a look at the `bpftrace` project as well, it might help you trace things without having to code the eBPF parts.