# `do_sys_open` vs `__x86_sys_open` when attaching kprobe

Tags: system-calls, ebpf, kprobe

I have tried running [opensnoop.py](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/opensnoop.py) but using

```
fnname_open='do_sys_open'
```

(which I have seen in other [scripts](https://github.com/rust-bpf/rust-bcc/blob/master/examples/opensnoop.rs)) instead of

```
fnname_open = b.get_syscall_prefix().decode() + 'open'
# = '__x86_sys_open' on Ubuntu 18.04
```

but the script then stops printing file names. What is causing the difference?

When using `attach_kprobe(event=fn)` is `fn` a system call or an event?

Do you get list of possible syscall from `/proc/kallsyms` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67766463/1374078)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BPF program attached to `__x86_sys_open` won't have the same result if you attach it to `do_sys_open` instead because those two functions don't have the same prototype:

```
long do_sys_open(int dfd, const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);
long sys_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);
```

So the `filename` argument, for example, won't be stored in the same register depending on which function you trace. You will need to edit the BPF program as well to fix this.